# ActionReducer Array<> or not for RxJS reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I want to figure the difference when we define `state: IUser` and `state: Array<IUser>`

I will elaborate more with the following lines of codes.

Can you **point out the differences** of declaring?

```
// in user.reducer.ts file

ActionReducer<IUser[]> = (state: Array<IUser> = [], action: Action): IUser[]

// in the store file
export interface IAppState {
  profile: IProfile;
  user: IUser[];
}

// all new reducers should be define here
const reducers = {
  profile: profileReducer,
  user: userReducer
};
```

VERSUS declaring:

```
ActionReducer<IUser> = (state: IUser, action: Action): IUser

// in the store.ts
export interface IAppState {
  profile: IProfile;
  user: IUser;
}

// all new reducers should be define here
const reducers = {
  profile: profileReducer,
  user: userReducer
};
```

---

FULL VERSIONS of the files:

```
import { Action, ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { USER_LIST_GET, USER_LIST_GET_SUCCESS, USER_LIST_GET_FAIL } from './user.actions';

export interface IUser {
  UserList?: Array<{}>;
  UserListError: boolean;
  isFetching: false;
}

export const userReducer: ActionReducer<IUser[]> = (state: Array<IUser> = [], action: Action): IUser[] => {

  switch (action.type) {

    case USER_LIST_GET:

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        UserListError: false
      });

    case USER_LIST_GET_SUCCESS:

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        UserList: action.payload
      });

    case USER_LIST_GET_FAIL:

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        UserListError: true
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

the store file

```
import { combineReducers, ActionReducer, Action, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { compose } from '@ngrx/core';
import { storeFreeze } from 'ngrx-store-freeze';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

export interface IAppState {
  profile: IProfile;
  user: IUser[];
}

// all new reducers should be define here
const reducers = {
  profile: profileReducer,
  user: userReducer
};

...
```

Comment: Are you asking how do you tell the difference between an object and an array?

Comment: I am asking for how to make a decision there, using Redux devtool plugin for Chrome, I see I get the same structure of data - `{user: { UserList: [ ] } }` for those 2 cases of declaration.

Comment: How you declare it doesn't matter because JavaScript is not a typed  language. TypeScript offers you a typing system, but its only for development. How the Chrome plugin sees the object is pure JavaScript

Comment: So there is no difference between the two ways. Because the type you supply is only for TypeScript support. Once it gets converted to JavaScript it's an object.